# How to handle parallel updates to the same MongoDB document?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, parallel-processing

Spring boot application with MongoDB CrudRepository.
I have multiple threads updating the same document in parallel. Each thread will load the document by ID, make changes 
and attempt to save it.
To overcome the "last wins" behavior that can override changes made by the first thread, i implemented a simple versioning mechanism where a thread can only save its changes if it's attempting to save the latest version, otherwise an exception is thrown.
This solves the data inconsistencies that multiple writes can cause but I'm loosing work. There's no retry mechanism for a thread that tried to save a document with an outdated version.
Are there any common solutions for this problem? I'm not sure which approach i need to take to handle this issue.

Comment: What's the use-case here? Is it a web application to guard against users performing operations potentially at the same time? A batch job that you have full controller over when things start and end?

Comment: It's a batch process that runs in the background. In the DB there's a document that serves as a report where each thread that is doing a task will update that report document with its results. These parallel tasks are the same with different context and i want to save every time a task ends (failure or success) to get the most updated status of the entire batch process.

Comment: Are there concurrent updates to the same fields in a document (so you need overall document versioning) or can you update fields discretely?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the updates are for the same fields.
The current implementation of versioning works fine i guess.. i just don't know how to handle "rejects"

Comment: @YarinZimmerman did you find any solution for this?